# MySql select right and like

Tags: mysql, sql

I haven't yet seen a post that can help me what Im trying to do.

This is the code I have:

```
select right(pcode, 5) from tosort;
```

id like to only show values that end with: `'%F12'`

this is what i have tried:

```
select right(pcode, 5) from tosort and pcode like '%F12';
```

Comment: `and` should be `where`

Comment: Thank you, where can I look into for simple solutions like that. My `and` `where` confuses me alittle

Comment: I suggest taking a look at sites like http://www.mysqltutorial.org/ and https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: thanks Nick appreciate the help..

Answer (score -2):

missing "%" sign at the end of the comparison variable
try this
select right(pcode, 5) from tosort and pcode like '%F12%';

Comment: No, OP is looking for a string that **end** with F12, not that **contains** F12 like you do with that % at the end